# Variable = class() in main script

Tags: python, class, variables, object, python-3.x

Just a simple question. What does the variable = class() means? I know what it does and why you use it. But how is the frase explained? Do you make an object out of the class with variable = class()? Or is it just a variable storing the class? Or do you call it an instance of a class perhaps?

For example:

```
myVariable = myClass()
```

Comment: Its an plain understanding... please have a look http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Comment: @Hariharan Yes but I have a lot of trouble understanding the docs.python.org because I'm a beginner. I know the question can seem a bit effortless but I'm really struggeling with understanding all of the different things you can do in Python. And I prefer to fully understand everything I write rather than just writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates an object and makes the `myVariable` an reference to the newly created object. And, yes you can call it an instance of the class.

If you are using CPython you can even check the memory address of the newly created object, like this

```
print id(myVariable)
```

If you want another variable to hold the class itself, you should do

```
myVariable = myClass
```

and then you can create objects or instances of the class with either of the names

```
myObject1 = myClass()
myObject2 = myVariable()
```

And in python, classes are named with initial capital words. Read this style guide about the class's naming convention http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Comment: I see, thank you very much! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can!

Answer (score 1):

it makes an object of `myClass`.

Comment: This is a bit misleading. Everything in Python is an object so `myClass` is an object already.